# Error 191 on Facebook, but URL is set up properly

Tags: facebook, api

Im getting issue with redirect_uri, but everything is set up properly.  I had left this code alone for a week when it was working fine,  picked it up again today and this error was there with no changes at all.

This is the URL for the app in settings:
http://www.shifty.com.br/europa/quemtemboca/app/
https://www.shifty.com.br/europa/quemtemboca/app/

This is the app page:
http://www.facebook.com/recifetest/

Sharing was working just fine, now it isnt with absolutely no changes.  Very weird.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: would you post the app url( the app namespace)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a recent bug (but should be resolved now).

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273845842724431?browse=search_5044c4ed200421b93855472

You can try this:

1 ) fill in the address into "Website with Facebook Login" => Site URL

2 ) fill in "App Domains" with your domain. ( you may not able to save, if you skip step 1 )

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same problem as well after the latest Facebook update.