# Facebook Page Tab : Error 191 (The specified URL is not owned by the application) but URLs are set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

For a contest page, I use Page Tab within a Facebook App, but I can't set a Share dialog without getting [this error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yodj7xjbf2edd00/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-14%2017.44.08.png).

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
    {
        FB.init({ appId: '##### (correctly set)', 
        status: true, 
       cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); 
    }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name:'name',
          link:'https://expertsmo.ca/_fb/concours/1', // https://apps.facebook.com/expertsmo
          caption:'test'
         });
    }
```

[Here is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqa7hqxuftbx1xf/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-14%2017.46.41.png) the App conf

I checked many posts on this error code, most of these problems are caused by the URL not being set; in my case, URL is well set and I still get this error. I tried many many things, still not working ( [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249930/error-191-on-facebook-but-url-is-set-up-properly/12250207#12250207) of a similar case doesn't seem to work because I can't find the field "Website With Facebook Login").

I also use PHP sdk to find out if the user likes the page already, or not.

Really, I can't find the solution to this problem ... any idea? Thanks...

Comment: your screens are still uploading right now, but i have answered already because it should definitely work with the correct settings. i will check out the screens when they are online.

Comment: It doesn't work because the FB.init never run.

Comment: @WizKid : Do you say that because they are in two different window.fbAsyncInit ? I tried to put the FB.ui immediately after init within the same window.fbAsyncInit and it still gives the same result. In fact, I have no error about FB.init in console

Comment: i edited my answer with a lot more information now

Comment: You set window.fbAsyncInit to a function that will run when the API have loaded. The second time you set it will override the first function. So only the second time will run. What you are doing is the same as: var a = func1; a = func2; a(); Which will call func2 and func1 will never been called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You include the JavaScript SDK two times in the code, only one time with an App ID (that is different from the `FB.init` call)**. Make sure you are using the latest code from the Facebook docs and clean up old stuff. That error message comes up when the App ID is not correct, the settings should be fine.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0

You also use window.fbAsyncInit in a wrong way, this should only be used once when you open the page. FB.ui should get called on user interaction or you will also get problems with popup blockers.

Btw, you should put ALL JavaScript code right before the closing body tag (for many reasons). Not sure why you put the async function after the opening body tag.

Comment: * 2 times window.fbAsyncInit  because this is php code between these 2 scripts (that I didn't copied here). 
* FB.ui : in my case it's called within the « Thank you » page after the user entered the contest. Woobox.com seems to do the same thing. Is it OK?
* I already have "Website" platform, the URL was slightly different, I changed it for the one your wrote me and it still doesn't work
* App domain is well set, [as you can see on my config here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqa7hqxuftbx1xf/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-14%2017.46.41.png)

Comment: then i assume you did not initialize the facebook sdk on your thank you page?

Comment: Important: Fix your HTML first. There is text before the doctype.

Comment: You can try it [here](https://expertsmo.ca/_fb/concours/1) doctype seems OK and FB.init is on the thank you page at the top

Comment: You are right, sdk was included 2 times ... I grouped it all together (I fix the thank you page later, [now the « landing » page should trigger a share popup)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r12ht9ajw15ncko/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202014-07-14%2018.25.49.png) – I still can't see the text before doctype in my source, is it already gone?

Comment: check out the link in my answer, that´s important

Comment: WOW. ok I am sorry, I did check it and add it, and somehow removed it I don't know how. Now it's working, thanks to you. May I ask you another question (less complex), if I want to share the Page Tab and not the website URL directly, should I add facebook.com in App domain?

Comment: i don´t think it is even possible to add facebook.com - even if it would be possible, it´s not needed and it should work without that too.

Comment: What do you mean? If I want people to share my Page Tab and I put "true" URL, they will share the URL and not the Page Tab (iframe on my Facebook page) ... is there a way to accomplish that? Thank you so much for your help ...

Comment: you can just share the page tab url too (facebook.com/yourpage/app_xxxxx), it should work without any additional settings for your app.

Comment: you´re welcome. thanx for the precious stackoverflow points :)